# App is greyed out

Tags: macos, finder, applications

What does it mean when an app is greyed out like this? It is not compatibility with OS X version because this grey thing just happened suddenly and I used to run this app a short time ago and I haven't updated OS X.

By the way, the app still runs. So there is not really any problem. I am just kind of curious as to why it is greyed out.

I'm running OS X 10.10.1.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if something is greyed out, it's unavailable, and a common reason is often that the file is being copied/part downloaded etc.  Scroll over to the right and check the file size of the item, and if the progress bar is present indicating a copy is happening.

[image]

Comment: This is not the case here. The app still runs, and it is not being copied.